# Should I proceed with multiple linear regression?

Tags: normal-distribution, multiple-regression

I initially planned to do **multiple linear regression** using four independent variables to predict one dependent variable (size) (n=142). All are ratio data.

Should I proceed with multiple linear regression, knowing that:

1. Only "size-tc" has Pearson's correlation that is statistically significant (p<0.05)
2. Shapiro-Wilk tests show non-normal pairwise distribution with the dependent variable

If multiple linear regression shouldn't be performed, is there anything I can do for this case?

Thank you!

PS: Sorry if I used the terms wrong. Trying to study stat at the moment.

[image: Pearson's correlations and Shapiro-Wilk test]

Comment: What do your scatterplots show?

Comment: Heteroscedasticity 
https://i.imgur.com/uBJdB6y.png

Comment: Your (1) and (2) are pretty much irrelevant. For guidance, read some of our threads about [regression diagnostics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=diagnostic%20assumption%20-logistic%20-binomial%20score%3a25%20is%3aanswer). Glen_b's answers dominate these hits, suggesting you might want to explore [his posts on regression diagnostics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A805+regression+diagnostic) further.  BTW, your images show no evidence of heteroscedasticity.  They show no problems at all: one would suspect these are randomly generated textbook data.